# Docker COPY is not copying script

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Docker COPY is not copying over the bash script

```
FROM alpine:latest

#Install Go and Tini - These remain.
RUN apk add --no-cache go build-base gcc go

RUN apk add --no-cache --update ca-certificates redis git && update-ca-certificates

# Set Env Variables for Go and add Go to Path.
ENV GOPATH /go
ENV PATH $GOPATH/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH

RUN go get github.com/rakyll/hey

RUN echo GOLANG VERSION `go version`
COPY ./bench.sh /root/bench.sh
RUN chmod +x /root/bench.sh
ENTRYPOINT /root/bench.sh
```

Here is the script -

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e;

echo "entered";

hey;
```

I try running the above Dockerfile with

```sh
$ docker build -t test-bench .
$ docker run -it test-bench
```

But I get the error

```
/bin/sh: /root/bench.sh: not found
```

The file **does** exist -

```
$ docker run --rm -it test-bench sh
/ # ls
bin    dev    etc    go     home   lib    media  mnt    opt    proc   root   run    sbin   srv    sys    tmp    usr    var
/ # cd root
~ # ls
bench.sh
~ #
```

Comment: Are you on a Windows host, and if so, can you check the line endings?  If you change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` you can also `docker run --rm -it test-bench sh` to get a debugging shell in a container based on that image to poke around.

Comment: I'm on a Mac. I did exec into the container and find that `bench.sh` is present in root.

Comment: Can you share some content of `bench.sh`? Does your script have a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Examples)?

Comment: updated question to include bench.sh

Comment: What is the Docker engine version??

Comment: Okay, the script is using `/bin/bash` the bash binary is not available in the alpine image. Either it has to be installed or a `/bin/sh` shell should be used

Comment: Both client and server are 19.03.2

Comment: @AvinashReddy That worked. Can you add that as the answer? I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your `docker build` successful. When I tried to simulate this, found the following error

```
 ---> Running in 96468658cebd
go: missing Git command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
package github.com/rakyll/hey: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
The command '/bin/sh -c go get github.com/rakyll/hey' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Try installing `git` using Dockerfile `RUN apk add --no-cache go build-base gcc go git` and run again.

The `COPY` operation here seems to be correct. Make sure it is present in the directory from where `docker build` is executed.

---

Okay, the script is using `/bin/bash` the bash binary is not available in the alpine image. Either it has to be installed or a `/bin/sh` shell should be used

Comment: Sorry, I missed the git line. Adding that gives me the same error.

Comment: @VBoi either add bash binary using `apk add bash` or modify the script to use /bin/sh